# What should be added on CORS whitelist domains before and after deployment

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, cors, app-engine-flexible

I have a react frontend and backend server running with node js. i wanted to enable CORS on specific domains to allow APIcalls to the backend. i added for example http://localhost . the front end and backend will be deployed on GCP App engine , my question is , what other domains i need to add to the white list after deployment

is there a way to set a specific domain name for the frontend so i can add it in the backend constant whitelist

Comment: The question is: do you want clients other than your own to be able to consume resources on your server? If not, your CORS configuration only needs to allow the Web origin of your frontend.

Comment: yes i only want my frontend , question is how to set a domain for frontend after deployment on app engine

Comment: What's the issue? That you don't know the Web origin of your frontend at the time of deploying your backend to App Engine? You can always redeploy your backend once you have that information.

Comment: Yes i am asking about the process i deploy frontend and get a url after deployment and then deploy the backend?

Comment: See my previous comment.